# Calling PHP functions with jQuery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm new to PHP and having some trouble calling PHP methods in through jQuery.

I'm using CodeIgniter. The method I want to call is in `/application/controllers/home.php` . Here's the relevant code:

```
<?php

class Home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    // Call the Controller constructor
    parent::__construct();

    ...
}

function addToCart() {
    // code to add to cart
}
```

The method I'm attempting to call is `addToCart`.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".addToCart").on('click', function () {
        var url = "<?= base_url() ?>home/addToCart";
        console.log('here');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {'id': 1},
            type: 'POST'
        });

        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Even though the path is correct, I keep getting a 404.

I can't seem to pin-point what is going wrong. Thank you for your help!

#### Fixed:

The `Home` controller was not the default controller for the app. I had to add `index.php` in front of it.

Comment: to check if the path is correct, just check the `view source`, and look at this line: `var url = "<?= base_url() ?>home/addToCart";` see if it does the url correctly

Comment: You can't call PHP methods with an AJAX call. You need some sort of connector program to accept your AJAX request and call the method for you.

Comment: It does part the url correctly: ```http://localhost/~<username>/<appname>/home/addToCart```

Comment: Is the method supposed to be camelcase in the URL? Try addtocart and add_to_cart

Comment: @MikeW if a method in a controller is not a "connector program", I don't know what is...

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I was not paying enough attention to the url, it was missing the ```index.php``` before the ```/home```

Comment: Hm, so - removed advice `to get a look to .htaccess` was a correct answer...